# CSS not applied when display flex is used in microsoft edge

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to apply border before and after the text. It works on all the browsers except for Microsoft edge and internet explorer. I'm using display: flex and please refer my code for details

I have tried setting max-width to 100% and adding box-sizing: border-box but doesn't seem to work

```
const text = styled(div)`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    ::before, ::after {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid gray;
      }
    ::before {
        margin-right: 8px;
      }
    ::after {
        margin-left:8px;
  }
`;
<text>OR</text>
```

I need the border to show up in IE 11 as well

Comment: It breaks only at times

Comment: display block or inline-block on the ::before ::after might help.

Comment: I tried that but it still breaks when I reload it twice or thrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE11 , you need to reset `display` on the pseudo element and reset also `flex-grow`.

Your code becomes :

```
const text = styled(div)`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    ::before, ::after {
        content: '';
        display:block;
        flex-grow:1;
        border-top: 1px solid gray;
      }
    ::before {
        margin-right: 8px;
      }
    ::after {
        margin-left:8px;
  }
`;
<text>OR</text>
```

Demo below to run with IE.

```css
text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  width:100%;
}

 text::before,
 text::after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  flex-grow:1 ;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

 text::before {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

 text::after {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<text>OR</text>
```

*is that the wandering haslayout ghost walking around since IE5 ??*

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by a video of Rachel Andrew's:

Grid to achieve this goal.

html:

```
<h1>OR</h1>
```

css:

```
h1 
{
   /* grid layout css */
   display: grid;
   align-items: center;
   gap: 8px;

   /* other css */
   color: gray;
   margin-bottom: 24px;
}

::before, ::after 
{
    content: '';
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
```

https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

You may want to use flex with grid wrapped in @supports https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports.

html layout using css in 2019 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XsZnCwbgwA

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Carol McKay's answer. The code can run well in Edge but not work in IE. So I modified it and below code can run well in Edge and IE11:

```css
h1 {
     /* grid layout css */
     display: grid;
     align-items: center;
     grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) auto minmax(0, 1fr);
     grid-gap: 8px;
     /* other css */
     color: gray;
     margin-bottom: 24px;
    }

h1::before, h1::after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     border-top: 1px solid gray;
    }
```

```html
<h1>OR</h1>
```